# Html.RenderAction not working in MVC 4 for dynamic CSS path

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem getting my layout.cshtml to have a dynamically chosen CSS file based on some business logic.

In my layout.cshtml I have the following in my head section:

```
<head>
    <link href="@{Html.RenderAction("CustomStyleSheetPath", "Shared");}" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

In my 'Shared' Controller, I have:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public virtual string CustomStyleSheetPath()
{
    string customCssPath = GetCssPath();  // e.g. "css/customStyleSheet.css"
    return customCssPath;
}
```

When I display the page, the css not pulled in correctly and I have the following when I view source:

```
<head>
    <linkcss\customStyleSheet.css href="" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

This code used to work in MVC 3 so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Html.Action` instead of `Html.RenderAction`

```
<link href="@(Html.Action("CustomStyleSheetPath)", "Shared"))" 
      rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`Html.Action` will return the rendered HTML in an `McvHtmlString` while `Html.RenderAction` writes directly to the response.

In MVC4 there is a new feature called [conditional attributes](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/) that's why it is not working.

Because `Html.RenderAction` won't return anything so the attribute `href` won't be rendered but the other hand `Html.RenderAction` writes directly to the response so you get this messed up result.

Comment: Thanks.  That's worked perfectly.  Thanks for the clarification on the difference between the RenderAction and Action